# Change specific detailLabelText

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm newbie in IOS development. How to set text for detailTextLabel, which in the second row using Swift?

I need something like this, but for the specific detailTextLabel:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Text"
```

Comment: Please provide a Logic Question !

Comment: @Kimble Did my answer help you out? Or is your problem different? If you go into a little more detail, it would make it much easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see, your problem is that you don't know how to change the text for each cell in your `UITableView` - your current method is obviously setting the same text for every cell.

Well what you need is an array with your different texts which allows you to add a different text string in each cell. The following is a basic example of how this can be done in `Objective-C`

Declare an array in your header (.h) file like so:

```
NSArray *detailArray;
```

In your implementation (.m) file, populate the array in your `viewDidLoad` method like so:

```
// Make an array and populate it.
detailArray = @[@"text one", @"text two", nil]; // etc....
```

When you are setting the `detailTextLabel` in your `UITableView` delegate methods, do the following to set the text label from the strings stored in the array:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", detailArray[indexPath.row]];
```